# Get first value from a criteria result java 8 (list of arrays I guess)

Tags: java, spring, criteria

I am doing a work for school on Java 8 with spring and hibernate. The thing is, I have a criteria that looks like this:

```
List<String> alumno_materia = session.createCriteria(Alumno_Materia.class)
         .add(Restrictions.eq("materia", materia))
         .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                 .add( Projections.groupProperty("dificultad") )
                 .add( Projections.rowCount(), "contador" )
         )
        .addOrder( Order.desc("contador"))
 .list();
```

The result of this criteria is[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91tSw.png):

```
alumno_materia = ArrayList size 2
   0 = {Object}
      0 = "dificil"
      1 = {Long} 2
   1 = {Object}
      0 = "facil"
      1 = {Long} 1
```

I need to access the string "dificil" (first row, first item).
But everytime I tried to save that variable to a string an exceltion happen that cannot cast to String.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ar.edu.unlam.tallerweb1.modelo.Alumno_Materia

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ar.edu.unlam.tallerweb1.modelo.Alumno_Materia
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code where you cast the item to a string?

Comment: I tried different things:


Change the class to be Alumno_Materia and then `alumno_materia.get(0).getDificultad();`


Tried to cast everything to a string 
`String result2 = (String) result.get(0);`


Tried to cast to a simple string 
`String result2 = result.toString();`


Tried a lot more that I can't remember anymore :(.